# TDD function design in D

Tags: tdd, d

When doing test driven development, I often find it useful to scaffold functions that intentionally fail testing, then fill in the details of the functions to achieve a "pass" for the unit tests.

In D, is there a standard way to scaffold an empty function, or otherwise approach this aspect of test-driven development?

For example, coming in the C# world `NotImplementedException` would be one way to achieve this:

```
int Foo(int x, int y) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Being new to D, I can see that there is a [base `Exception` class](https://dlang.org/phobos/object.html#.Exception), that all exceptions seem to inherit from. But is there a better way to scaffold new functions in a TDD D environment?

Comment: You can simply define your own NotImplementedException too.

Comment: I would use `assert(false, "Not implemented");`. It's short, doesn't require a specific exception type to cover this specific case, and does exactly what's needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally I use `assert(false)`.  And I have seen this used by others as well.  You can also add a message `assert (false, "Unimplemented")`

D does not have as many types of exceptions as C#.  Unless the exception would have reason to be caught in a try-catch it is merely a message for a human (coder) so there is no real reason to have code representation for an exception type.

You could also just throw a generic exception but using assert is more convenient.

(the doc for assert https://dlang.org/spec/contracts.html)

Comment: so I'm of the opinion that generic exceptions are terrible and exception messages ought to be considered harmful... and the reason D uses them so much is just that's what the core language and stdlib has made *convenient* to use. That said though, for unimplemented, `assert(0 /* or false */)` *is* a decent way to go for this.